# .NET & Swagger started to get 401 error

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger, swashbuckle

I have configured Swagger for my .NET Core webApi application, here is the configuration for it

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddAuth();

            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
                    builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                        .AllowAnyMethod()
                        .AllowAnyHeader()
                        .AllowCredentials()
                        .Build());
            });

            services.AddMvc();
            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1",
                    new Info
                    {
                        Version = "v1",
                        Title = "XXX Synchronization API",
                        Description = "XXX Synchronization API",
                        TermsOfService = "None",
                        Contact = new Contact { Name = "XXX Inc.", Email = "XXXX", Url = "XXX.com" }
                    });
                c.IncludeXmlComments(GetXmlCommentsPath());
                c.DescribeAllEnumsAsStrings();
            });

            services.AddSingleton<IHashProvider, Pbkdf2Version1HashProvider>();
            services.AddSingleton<IPasswordHasher, PasswordHasher>();
            services.AddTransient<IAuthenticationService, GfdAuthenticationService>();
            services.AddSingleton(new GfdSqlServerDatabase(Gfd2Configuration.Settings.GfdSqlServerConnectionString));
            services.AddSingleton(new MySqlSyncDatabase(Gfd2Configuration.Settings.AwsMySqlConnectionString));
            services.AddTransient<SyncRepository, AwsMySqlSyncRepository>();
            services.AddHostedService<QueuedHostedService>();
            services.AddSingleton<IBackgroundTaskQueue, BackgroundTaskQueue>();
            services.AddSingleton<ArchivedJobProcessorBase, ArchivedJobProcessorFeatures>();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="app"></param>
        /// <param name="env"></param>
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
            app.UseMvc();

            app.UseSwagger();

#if DEBUG
            app.UseSwaggerUI(c => { c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "XXXX Synchronization API V1"); });
#else
            app.UseSwaggerUI(c => { c.SwaggerEndpoint("/sync/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "XXX Synchronization API V1"); });
#endif
        }
```

and everything was wokring fine. And for some reason this morning anytime I open the `/swagger` url I'm getting a 401 error.
I don't need any authentication for the Swagger docs and UI, all is public.

Could this be related to `.NET Core 2.1.2`?

using `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore 3.0.0`

Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: That's because you placed `app.UseAuthentication();` **BEFORE** `app.UseSwaggerUI(...)`. Middlewares are executed in the order of registrations

Comment: I moved it after the `UseSwaggerUI` and got some 401 error. Something else is here.

Comment: In my case the tip from @Tseng helped. Thnx.

Answer (score 1):

For those who might have such an issue, the fix was actually quite simple. For one of my new webApi controllers which actually requires authentication, I forgot to add the attribute `[Route("api/[controller]")]`, as such the `/swagger` url was pointing to that controller and thus the 401 error. Go figure :)

Answer (score 1):

This issue happened to me when I added a new endpoint with wrong route.

I used `[Route("/{id}")]`.

It should have no forward slash at the beginning `[Route("{id}")]`

Answer (score 0):

Recently I got the same 401 error. The decision was to add "Bearer " in the Value field on the Swagger-authorization page before a token's value.